# How can I add embed function to a page

Tags: javascript, html, embed

How can I add this function to something: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ec17ri8dc
Its from this page.

Notice when you click on it a popup appears with the generated html to add the code somewhere. Have ben unable to find a good google search query that doesn't bring up irrelevant pages.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: your question to me isnt clear.  If you're looking for the way to get the popup to work, thats using fancybox.  -> http://fancybox.net/

Comment: nevermind, you're wanting to add an embed button that generates the html code.  I've always handrolled those.  I am not sure there is a standard way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I as wondering if there was a standard way of doing this than handrolling the js. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [quick solution](http://jsbin.com/omukuw/2/edit).

If you know some basic jQuery you won't have problems with understanding the code but feel free to ask if you need any help.

Keep in mind that the code won't trigger a pop-up, it's just to get the embed code. I'd suggest using some plugin for this, fancybox is a good one.